# Cannot put() data to an indexeddb database using Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

Hi I created an Indexeddb database but having trouble input data into it.
Database:

```
var request = indexedDB.open("BCDB");

request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
    var db = request.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore("psf", { autoIncrement: true });
    var psTag = store.createIndex("ps_tag", "psTag");
    var psNameIndex = store.createIndex("ps_name", "psName");
    var psResultIndex = store.createIndex("ps_result", "psResult");  
    var psDateIndex = store.createIndex("ps_date", "psDate"); 
};

request.onsuccess = function() {
    db = request.result;
};
```

I could see the database was created on the "Storage" windows of Firefox but when I tried to input something into it, it just didn't work.

```
var tx = db.transaction("psf", "readwrite");
var store = tx.objectStore("psf");

var request = store.put({
    psName: "ABC",
    psTag: "XYZ",
    psDate: "DEF",
    psResult: "QWE"
});

request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    alert('done');
};

request.onerror = function(e) {
    alert(e.value);
};
```

This problem only occurs on Firefox. I can input successfully on Chrome. I isolated and figure out it was the put() that failed but it was OK on Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code shows that you simply want to insert some data in the database, so why to use `put()`, instead use `add()` which is meant for the purpose.
`put()` is update something in database while `add()` is to insert.
Check - [IDBObjectStore API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore)

```
var request = store.add({
    psName: "ABC",
    psTag: "XYZ",
    psDate: "DEF",
    psResult: "QWE"
});
```

**UPDATE: With POC sample**
Check below code, it will work whether you use `put()` or `add()`. Give a try and it should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Stackoverflow</title>
    <script>
        var DB_handler = null
        var request = indexedDB.open("BCDB");

        request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
            var db = request.result;
            var store = db.createObjectStore("psf", { autoIncrement: true });
            var psTag = store.createIndex("ps_tag", "psTag");
            var psNameIndex = store.createIndex("ps_name", "psName");
            var psResultIndex = store.createIndex("ps_result", "psResult");  
            var psDateIndex = store.createIndex("ps_date", "psDate"); 
        };

        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
            DB_handler = event.target.result;
            var tx = DB_handler.transaction("psf", "readwrite");
            var store = tx.objectStore("psf");

            var request = store.add({
                psName: "ABC",
                psTag: "XYZ",
                psDate: "DEF",
                psResult: "QWE"
            });

            request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                alert('done');
                var transaction = DB_handler.transaction(["psf"]);
                var objectStoreHandler = transaction.objectStore("psf");
                var cursorHandler = objectStoreHandler.openCursor();

                cursorHandler.onerror = function(event) {
                    if (errorCallBack && typeof(errorCallBack) == 'function') {
                        errorCallBack(event);
                    }
                };

                cursorHandler.onsuccess = function(event) {
                    var cursor = event.target.result;
                    if (cursor) {
                        if(cursor.value != null && cursor.value != undefined){
                            console.log(cursor.value);
                        }
                    }
                };

            };

            request.onerror = function(e) {
                alert(e.value);
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

My Firefox version is 38.0.1. Can you check your Firefox version if it is too old for have IndexedDB, because `add()` and `put()` are basic functions so they should be implemented properly.

Comment: Well because since I learned  IDB (which is yesterday), everyone seems to use _put()_ but not _add()_.
About the function, it does not work either. I used the exact same thing I had used on Google Chrome but nothing worked.

Comment: Ok, not a problem, we are all here to learn. Now remember you should use `add()` for inserts and `put()` for updated. Check my edit, I have given you a sample POC.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used the latest version too. But it doesn't work either. You code works perfectly on Google Chrome
http://i.imgur.com/0X3C6Ij.jpg

Comment: What about Firefox, did you try this code in FF? What is your FF version?

Comment: Yes check out the image. It was the result on Firefox. Version 38.0.1 latest of course.
And this is the Google Chrome result http://i.imgur.com/damBvHe.jpg. Works perfect everytime. I just don't understand why it fails at all on Firefox.

Comment: Hey buddy, it is working. It is just that in FF you are able to see the database which is visible in Chrome, but it doesn't mean that IndexedDB code is not working. "Done" alert comes only from the success of put/add, so it is working. Also, you can check console and you should be able to see `Object {psName: "ABC", psTag: "XYZ", psDate: "DEF", psResult: "QWE"}`

Comment: _An IndexedDB transaction that was not yet complete has been aborted due to page navigation._

I saw no log at first then I refreshed. Then the warning above showed and then it worked (showed on log). Whew, thank you.